# jQuery resize event handler, capture the original width and height of a certain element before resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, it works, but I hate it :) and I want to make something cleaner.

The idea is:
- I have added a resize event handler to the window object;
- I use a setTimeout to make my code wait for the user to finish resizing, when... the doneResizing function kicks in and calls a method - **Canvas.resize() method to be exact.**

Where I feel I'm doing it wrong is here:
**I need to capture both the original width and height of "canvas" element and also the "width" and  "height" of that elem after resize.**

Right now I am doing it using global variables (global in another scope, does not matter), do you know a way to do this better?

```
function doneResizing() {
    if (Canvas.isInitialized()) {
        $timeout(function() {
            var cw = element.width();
            var ch = element.height();
            // Resize the svg.
            $('#canvas svg').width(cw);
            $('#canvas svg').height(ch);
            Canvas.resize(iw, ih, cw, ch, $('#canvas'), $('#canvas svg'));
            iw = null;
            ih = null;
        }, 10);
    }
};

var id;
var iw, ih;
$(window).resize(function(event) {
    clearTimeout(id);
    if (!iw) iw = element.width();
    if (!ih) ih = element.height();
    element.addClass('loading');
    $('#canvas svg').hide();    
    id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);    
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements as I read it are:

- You need to record the initial size, *before* you start resizing as once resize starts you will not know the original size accurately.
- You need to ignore multiple reizes until the user stops resizing, so a time delay is appropriate, but you need to clear the timer if another resize comes in.
- Your second setTimeout should not be required.

You are already doing most of this, so a couple of tweaks should finish it:

```
var id;
// record the initial size
var iw = element.width();
var ih = element.height();

$(window).resize(function (event) {
    clearTimeout(id);
    element.addClass('loading');
    $('#canvas svg').hide();
    id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
});

function doneResizing() {
    if (Canvas.isInitialized()) {
        var cw = element.width();
        var ch = element.height();
        // Resize the svg.
        $('#canvas svg').width(cw);
        $('#canvas svg').height(ch);
        Canvas.resize(iw, ih, cw, ch, $('#canvas'), $('#canvas svg'));
        // Now record the last position as the new start size
        iw = cw;
        ih = ch;
    }
};
```

You have not shown the code that supplies the `element`, so there is scope (no pun intended) to put all this in a function and reference your globals on `window`, or in a namespace (really another *one-shot* nested wrapping function).

Comment: Yes, it's a nice tweak :) setting the iw and ih at the end. Then I could remove the "if (!iw) iw = element.width();". What I hoped, was for the .resize() method to have initial width and height built it... but obviously it does not. :) Ty

Comment: Missed removing those - sorry :)